# AMP refferer from subdomain domain.cdn.ampproject.org

Tags: amp-html

Since the 27th of january I get according to analytics referrer from
http://www-usa--reisetipps-net.cdn.ampproject.org/v/www.usa-reisetipps.net/...

Before that they came normally from http://cdn.ampproject.org/v/www.usa-reisetipps.net/...
The new Refferer can not be opened.
Does anyone know the background of the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're talking about the sub-domain changes in AMP, check the full [AMP Cache Updates](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/amp-cache-updates.html) announcement:

> AMP Cache Updates Monday, December 5, 2016 Posted by John Coiner,
>   Software Engineer
>
> "Today we are announcing a change to the domain scheme of the Google
>   AMP Cache. Beginning soon, the Google AMP Cache will serve each site
>   from its own subdomain of https://cdn.ampproject.org. This change will
>   allow content served from the Google AMP Cache to be protected by the
>   fundamental security model of the web: the HTML5 origin."

Additional reading on updates:

[UPDATES NEEDED FOR HOSTS AND SERVICE PROVIDERS WITH REMOTE ENDPOINTS](https://amphtml.wordpress.com/2016/12/05/amp-cache-updates/):

> Due to the changes described above, CORS endpoints will begin seeing
>   requests with new origins. The following updates will be required:
>
> - Expand request acceptance to the new subdomain: Sites that currently only accept CORS requests from https://cdn.ampproject.org and the
>     publisher’s own origins must update their systems to accept requests
>     from https://%5Bpub-com].cdn.ampproject.org,
>     https://cdn.ampproject.org, and the AMP publisher’s own origins.
> - Tighten request acceptance for security: Sites that currently accept CORS requests from https://*.ampproject.org as described in the AMP
>     spec, can improve security by restricting acceptance to requests from
>     https://%5Bpub-com].cdn.ampproject.org, https://cdn.ampproject.org,
>     and the AMP publisher’s own origins. Support for
>     https://*.ampproject.org is no longer necessary.
> - Support for new subdomain pattern by ads, analytics, and other technology providers: Service providers such as analytics and ads
>     vendors that have a CORS endpoint will also need to ensure that their
>     systems accept requests from the Google AMP Cache’s subdomains
>     (e.g.https://ampbyexample-com.cdn.ampproject.org), in addition to
>     their own hosts.